# Can I use python-docx-template (docxtpl) to auto populate "chunks" of a word document dynamically?

Tags: python, python-docx, docxtpl

I have been writing a reporting system in python and I want to generate a document based on a docx template.

After researching for solutions it appears that the python-docx-template library takes in a template with a jinja2 syntax, fills in the blanks as required, and then outputs a word document, which would suit my needs perfectly, however my document looks like the following:

[image: Template Document Sample Image]

Multiple sets of these "issues" would exist in the document, so per issue a styled issue paragraph header, as well as a table with the issue data in it would need to be generated.

I cant figure out if the library will allow me to dynamically generate both the styled header and table per issue as a set, or if I'm going about the solution the wrong way, and there is a better way to output into word documents based on a complex template.